# How to integrate FCM notification in VUE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building web application in Vue using webpack. Currently I want to integrate FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) notification in web app to sent notification to users.

I gone through this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0 but I am not able to integrate it in Vue

Comment: I explained how to configure an Vue app to handle notifications in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153913/9661304

Answer (score 1):

3 steps:

1. `npm i firebase`
2. add to main.ts the following..

   `firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey: "YOUR KEY", authDomain: "...", databaseURL: "", projectId: "", storageBucket: "", messagingSenderId: "", appId: "" });let messaging!: firebase.messaging.Messaging; if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) { messaging = firebase.messaging(); } export { messaging };`
3. add to public folder =>

   `importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js"); importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js"); firebase.initializeApp({ messagingSenderId: "YOUR SENDER_ID" });const messaging = firebase.messaging();`

Thats is all!