# Vue pwa with firebase cloud messaging not working properly

Tags: firebase, vue.js, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

im trying the following code:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then((registration) => {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging().useServiceworker(registration)
        console.log(messaging)
        messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
          console.log('Notification permission granted.')
          messaging.getToken().then(function (currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
              console.log(currentToken)
            }
          })
        })
      })
```

my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Herot-Eyes",
  "short_name": "herot-eyes",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/static/img/icons/herot-eyes-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/static/img/icons/herot-eyes-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/static/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png",
      "sizes": "180x180",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3"
}
```

what is going wrong? my console.log(messaging) is returning a factory error, the following:

> bad-push-set : "The FCM push set used for storage / lookup was not not
>   a valid push set string." bad-scope
>
> "The service worker scope must be a string with at least one
>   character." bad-sender-id
>
> "Please ensure that 'messagingSenderId' is set correctly in the
>   options passed into firebase.initializeApp()." bad-subscription
>
> "The subscription must be a valid PushSubscription." bad-token : "The
>   FCM Token used for storage / lookup was not a valid token string."
>   bad-vapid-key
>
> "The public VAPID key is not a Uint8Array with 65 bytes."
>   bg-handler-function-expected
>
> "The input to setBackgroundMessageHandler() must be a function."
>   delete-scope-not-found
>
> "The deletion attempt for service worker scope could not be performed
>   as the scope was not found." delete-token-not-found
>
> "The deletion attempt for token could not be performed as the token
>   was not found." failed-delete-vapid-key
>
> "The VAPID key could not be deleted."
>   failed-serviceworker-registration
>
> "We are unable to register the default service worker.
>   {$browserErrorMessage}" failed-to-delete-token
>
> "Unable to delete the currently saved token." get-subscription-failed
>
> "There was an error when trying to get any existing Push
>   Subscriptions." incorrect-gcm-sender-id
>
> "Please change your web app manifest's 'gcm_sender_id' value to
>   '103953800507' to use Firebase messaging." invalid-delete-token
>
> "You must pass a valid token into deleteToken(), i.e. the token from
>   getToken()." invalid-public-vapid-key
>
> "The public VAPID key must be a string." invalid-saved-token
>
> "Unable to access details of the saved token."
>   no-fcm-token-for-resubscribe
>
> "Could not find an FCM token and as a result, unable to resubscribe.
>   Will have to resubscribe the user on next visit." no-sw-in-reg
>
> "Even though the service worker registration was successful, there was
>   a problem accessing the service worker itself."
>   no-window-client-to-msg
>
> "An attempt was made to message a non-existant window client."
>   notifications-blocked
>
> "Notifications have been blocked." only-available-in-sw
>
> "This method is available in a service worker context."
>   only-available-in-window
>
> "This method is available in a Window context." permission-blocked
>
> "The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead."
>   permission-default
>
> "The required permissions were not granted and dismissed instead."
>   public-vapid-key-decryption-failed
>
> "The public VAPID key did not equal 65 bytes when decrypted."
>   should-be-overriden
>
> "This method should be overriden by extended classes."
>   sw-reg-redundant
>
> "The service worker being used for push was made redundant."
>   sw-registration-expected
>
> "A service worker registration was the expected input."
>   token-subscribe-failed
>
> "A problem occured while subscribing the user to FCM: {$message}"
>   token-subscribe-no-push-set
>
> "FCM returned an invalid response when getting an FCM token."
>   token-subscribe-no-token
>
> "FCM returned no token when subscribing the user to push."
>   token-unsubscribe-failed
>
> "A problem occured while unsubscribing the user from FCM: {$message}"
>   token-update-failed
>
> "A problem occured while updating the user from FCM: {$message}"
>   token-update-no-token
>
> "FCM returned no token when updating the user to push."
>   unable-to-resubscribe
>
> "There was an error while re-subscribing the FCM token for push
>   messaging. Will have to resubscribe the user on next visit.
>   {$message}" unsupported-browser
>
> "This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase
>   SDK." use-sw-before-get-token
>
> "You must call useServiceWorker() before calling getToken() to ensure
>   your service worker is used."

Comment: For those who like to use Vue Official PWA, tutorial with FCM- https://link.medium.com/IfVnGfdp20

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Configure to server to receive notifications

Inside public folder, add the following line to **manifest.json**:

```
{
    //...manifest properties
    "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507" <--- add this line to the file
}
```

**Note: if the project wasn't created using Vue Cli, manually create the *manifest.json* file.** (Thanks @natghi)

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
  messagingSenderId: <Sender ID>
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

In your main.js file add the following code

```
var config = {
  apiKey: <API_KEY>,
  authDomain: <DOMAIN>,
  databaseURL: <DATABASE_URL>,
  projectId: <PROJECT_ID>,
  storageBucket: <STORAGE_BUCKET>,
  messagingSenderId: <SENDER_ID>
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

Vue.prototype.$messaging = firebase.messaging()

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then((registration) => {
    Vue.prototype.$messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

### Receive notifications

Then in your App.vue, add this code to the created() function

```
created() {
    var config = {
        apiKey: <API_KEY>,
        authDomain: <DOMAIN>,
        databaseURL: <DATABASE_URL>,
        projectId: <PROJECT_ID>,
        storageBucket: <STORAGE_BUCKET>,
        messagingSenderId: <SENDER_ID>
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging
    .requestPermission()
    .then(() => firebase.messaging().getToken())
    .then((token) => {
        console.log(token) // Receiver Token to use in the notification
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
    });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
    // ...
    });
}
```

### Send notification

### UPDATE

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

var serviceAccount = require("./certificate.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
const Messaging = admin.messaging()

var payload = {
    webpush: {
        notification: {
            title: "Notification title",
            body: "Notification info",
            icon: 'http://i.imgur.com/image.png',
            click_action: "http://yoursite.com/redirectPage" 
        },
    },
    topic: "Doente_" + patient.Username
};

return Messaging.send(payload)
```

#### Older version

Then, in postman you do the following request

```
POST /v1/projects/interact-f1032/messages:send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer <SENDER_TOKEN>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "message":{
    "token" : The token that was in the console log,
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

### Sender Token

In your backend, use the following code, where the file "certificate.json" was got in the firebase dashboard (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client - Generate pair of keys)

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var key = require('./certificate.json');
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
}

getAccessToken().then(senderToken => console.log(senderToken))
```

The senderToken is used on the Authorization header to send a notification

Comment: Your updated solution almost works. If I use your code as provided, you will get an error that firebase is already initialized. Therefore you need to use this.$messaging in your App.vue instead of reinitializing firebase. That worked for me.

Comment: Replace 

var config = {
        apiKey: <API_KEY>,
        authDomain: <DOMAIN>,
        databaseURL: <DATABASE_URL>,
        projectId: <PROJECT_ID>,
        storageBucket: <STORAGE_BUCKET>,
        messagingSenderId: <SENDER_ID>
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

With

this.$messaging ?
Because my code used to work when I tested

Comment: can you help me how to get certificate.json this file

Comment: @DarshanDave https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app Here you have you can you get the certificate

Comment: What error are you getting? It has been working since I posted it here for everyone

Comment: It works when we use this.$messaging instead of messaging and does not initialize firebase in App.vue

Comment: This solution works perfectly.Thank you!. The only thing i think you should clarify is that {
    "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
} should go into the object already created by the CLI(if there is already one). I made the mistake of having 2 objects and this caused an error.

Comment: ohh sorry about that, I'll edit that so it's clear, thanks!