# How should I set up Firebase Cloud Messaging in vuejs?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know the proper way of setting up the firebase-cloud-messaging in vuejs. I'm a novice in this and I'm at lost from the official FCM docs' guide. I really don't know where to put the things that the docs says in my vue app. If possible, I want to know the set up in detail. Please, guide me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a tutorial that is with firebase and vuejs like this one 

https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c

Comment: I can do authentication with firebase. I'm now in trouble with push notification which is cloud messaging feature. I want to know the proper way to set up firebase cloud messaging in vuejs

Comment: I explained how to configure an Vue app to handle notifications in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153913/9661304